VBA to print each table row to pdf using last table column as the filename
I need to export details of each Table row (Table1) to pdf, setting the filename from the column Table1[Student ID] for each exported row.  It would be ideal to exclude blank cells in the row from the export.
As a beginner, I have most of the logical elements needed from searching similar questions, but struggle with the native order of VBA.
The last column [Student ID] must be the pdf filename to enable the file upload.
Sub ExportTableRowToPDF()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim rw As ListRow
Dim pdfFile As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")

For Each rw In tbl.ListRows

If Application.WorksheetFunction.countA(rw.Range) > 0 Then

pdfFile = rw.Range.Cells(1, tbl.ListColumns.Count).Value & ".pdf"

rw.Range.Copy
ws.Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = rw.Range.Address & ":" & rw.Range.Cells(1, tbl.ListColumns.Count).Address
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=pdfFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End If

Next rw

End Sub


You will get best results if you include some code in your post, even if it's not working exactly as you want.  Questions with no attempted code tend to get closed.

You inserted the code marking it It seems to work. Then what is the question referring to your post?

The question I asked was answered by me essentially.  I needed someone to answer more quickly than I could.

In this case you can also post your answer as an answer, but for this you need at least 15 reputations. How to answer my own question

Excel Table Rows to PDF
Table

PDFs


The Code
Sub ExportTableRowsToPDF()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Export Table Rows To PDF"
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const TABLE_NAME As String = "Table1"
    Const CRITERIA_COLUMN_TITLE As String = "StudentID"
    Const MIN_NON_BLANK_COLUMNS_COUNT As Long = 2

    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Determine the destination path.
    Dim pdfFolderPath As String: pdfFolderPath = wb.Path ' !?
    
    ' Reference the worksheet, table ('ListObject') and column ('ListColumn').
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(TABLE_NAME)
    ' This allows the column to be anywhere.
    Dim lc As ListColumn: Set lc = tbl.ListColumns(CRITERIA_COLUMN_TITLE)
    
    ' Reference the data range and return its values in an array.
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = tbl.DataBodyRange
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    
    ' Retrieve the criteria column and the number of columns.
    Dim CriteriaColumn As Long: CriteriaColumn = lc.Index
    Dim ColumnsCount As Long: ColumnsCount = rg.Columns.Count
    
    ' Determine the maximum number of blank columns.
    Dim MaxBlankColumnsCount As Long:
    MaxBlankColumnsCount = rg.Columns.Count - MIN_NON_BLANK_COLUMNS_COUNT
    
    ' Export only if the criteria cell contains no error, is not blank,
    ' and if at least the number of columns specified is not blank.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim hws As Worksheet, hcell As Range, rrg As Range, urg As Range
    Dim Value As Variant, r As Long, sColumn As Long, ExportedRowsCount As Long
    Dim pdfPath As String
    Dim WasHelperSheetAdded As Boolean, IsRowValid As Boolean
    Dim IsBlankFound As Boolean, WasRowExported As Boolean
    
    For r = 1 To rg.Rows.Count
        ' Retrieve...
        Value = Data(r, CriteriaColumn)
        Set rrg = rg.Rows(r)
        ' Reset flags.
        IsRowValid = False
        IsBlankFound = False
        ' Check if row is valid.
        If Not IsError(Value) Then ' not an error
            If Len(Value) > 0 Then ' not blank
                If Application.CountBlank(rrg) <= MaxBlankColumnsCount Then
                    IsRowValid = True
                    ' On the first valid row, add a helper sheet.
                    If Not WasHelperSheetAdded Then
                        Set hws = wb.Sheets.Add
                        WasHelperSheetAdded = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
        ' Export row.
        If IsRowValid Then
            ' Combine the blank cells in a unioned range.
            IsBlankFound = False
            Set urg = Nothing
            For sColumn = 1 To ColumnsCount
                If Len(CStr(Data(r, sColumn))) = 0 Then
                    If IsBlankFound Then
                        Set urg = Union(urg, rrg.Cells(sColumn))
                    Else
                        Set urg = rrg.Cells(sColumn)
                        IsBlankFound = True
                    End If
                End If
            Next sColumn
            ' Hide bank columns.
            If IsBlankFound Then
                urg.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End If
            ' Copy the visible columns to the helper sheet.
            Set hcell = hws.Range("A1")
            With rrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                .Copy
                hcell.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
                hcell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            End With
            ' Export from the helper sheet to PDF.
            pdfPath = pdfFolderPath _
                & Application.PathSeparator & Value & ".pdf"
            WasRowExported = False
            With hcell.CurrentRegion
                On Error Resume Next
                    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                        Filename:=pdfPath, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
                        OpenAfterPublish:=False
                    WasRowExported = (Err.Number = 0)
                On Error GoTo 0
                .Clear
            End With
            If WasRowExported Then
                ExportedRowsCount = ExportedRowsCount + 1
            Else
                MsgBox "Could not export as """ & pdfPath & """!", _
                    vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            End If
            ' Show all columns.
            If IsBlankFound Then
                rrg.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            End If
        'Else ' the row is invalid
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Delete the helper sheet.
    If WasHelperSheetAdded Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' suppress delete sheet dialog
            hws.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' Inform.
    
    If ExportedRowsCount > 0 Then
        MsgBox ExportedRowsCount & " row" _
            & IIf(ExportedRowsCount = 1, "", "s") & " exported.", _
            vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    Else
        MsgBox "No rows exported.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
    End If
    
End Sub

Message Boxes


Created Files

